# Show/hide table rows

Tags: visualforce, table

I'm trying to allow the toggling of table rows for a set of tables on a page:

```
<apex:repeat var="dev" value="{!userList}">

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!dev.projectMap}" var="project" id="userTable" rendered="{!tableVisible}" columnsWidth="20%,8%" ondblclick="ToggleRows('{!$Component.userTable}')" rowClasses="dataRowHide">

        <apex:column headerValue="{!dev.userName.name}" id="devHeader" >

            <apex:outputLink id="dataDev" target="_blank" value="/{!project}" rendered="{!IF(project == null, false, true)}" >{!IF(project == caseID, 'Current Case', project)}</apex:outputLink> <!-- Set to caseNumber? -->

        </apex:column>
        <apex:repeat value="{!dev.projectMap[project]}" var="date">

        <apex:column headerValue="{!dev.totalHourMap[date]}" id="hourHeader"  headerClass="{!dev.colColor[date]}" > 
             <apex:outputText id="dataOutput" rendered="{!IF(project == null || project == caseID, false, true)}">{!dev.projectMap[project][date]}</apex:outputText>
             <apex:inputText id="dataInput" rendered="{!IF(project == caseID, true, false)}" value="{!dev.projectMap[project][date]}" style="width:20%"/>

        </apex:column>

        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:repeat>
```

The table is initially not rendered while the user selects an option; when rendered, each table's data rows should be hidden until the user double clicks on the header row.

I've tried to use an action support tag to call a method that changes the rowClasses CSS(which worked fine for header colors), but that didn't quite work right.

I've also tried to use Javascript, but I'm not that strong with it and can't seem to get onDblClick to fire.

Comment: Can you post your actionSupport?  Note that you have to rerender an outer element (e.g. devHeader) if you want the inner element (e.g. dataDev) "rendered" attribute to be recalculated.

Comment: Sure, I used this tag:  <apex:actionSupport event="ondblclick" action="{!dev.toggleVisible}" reRender="userTable" immediate="true" /> underneath the "devheader" tag. That fired the toggleVisible event, but the CSS didn't change and it was only fired when double-clicking the row data, instead of the header as I'd hoped.